# How to request authentication to all routes except welcome which has to be the login page in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-security

I want to request authentication to all available routes except one "/welcome" which has to be the login page too!

I'm using Spring Boot Security and my SecurityFilterChain is coded like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/welcome")
                .and().httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I want the user to be redirected to the welcome url/page when not authenticated. And when authenticated to be redirected to the root "/". However with this configuration the server keeps telling me **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Where am I doing wrong?
How to allow public access only to the "/welcome" url and not the rest?

Comment: what you are looking for is `http.anyRequest().authenticated()` instead of `requestMatchers("/**")`. Also in the future, enable debug logging and post logs when you are asking.

Comment: Sorry @Toerktumlare I'm starting learning spring. But what you say works only if I don't use "welcome" as login page

Comment: What you are claiming is not correct, please post a working exampel showing what you are claiming